# How to Run .jar methods from Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, google-chrome, jar

I have a java jar with classes in it. I need to be able to call a method in one of those classes. It has to be on the client side locally, not ajax calls to a server not webservices. I have the .jar right next to my html page and I need to be able to make a java method call from javascript/html.

I just need **a way** to call the java method, these ways I tried might not even be the best way to do it. Just looking for some help.

I have tried multiple ways already all of with no prevail. Maybe I did something wrong, or `<applet>` is no longer supported by [chrome v42 and up.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033)

**Java** class inside of **.jar**

```
import java.applet.Applet;


public class MethodInvocation extends Applet{

    public String helloWorld() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        return "Hello JavaScript, I came from Java";
    }

}
```

**First Attempt** - Didn't work get that [chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033) message

```
    <applet archive="JavaLibrary.jar" code="MethodInvocation.class" name="myApplet" width="1" height="1"></applet>

    <script language="javascript">
        var javaMessage = document.myApplet.helloWorld();
        console.log("Java Message Received: " + javaMessage);
    </script>
```

**Second Attempt** - Applet shows up with puzzle piece in middle of it saying "The plugin is not supported" and in the console I this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined`.

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
    <param name="id" value="app">
    <param name="code" value="MethodInvocation">
    <param name="archive" value="JavaLibrary.jar">
</object>

<script language="javascript">
    app.helloWorld();
</script>
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that you're not going to be able to do what you're attempting. Even if applets still worked, you can't just treat any old .jar file as if it were an applet.

Comment: I have a very similar issue and have been all over the Oracle site. When not using a jar ie. `<applet id="TDAPP" name="TDAPP" code="TDecoderApplet.class" codebase="files/" width="5" height="5" > </applet> ` everything works perfectly. As soon as I try jar the class files I get _'Error: Error calling method on NPObject!'_ in the console. I don't know what I should be doing to fix this.

Comment: This is how I tried using a jar file: `<applet id="TDAPP" name="TDAPP" code="TDecoderApplet.class" archive="files/TDAPP.jar" width="5" height="5" >
  </applet>`. On the Oracle site there is much talk of the manifest file for security issues. I don't think I'm that far along with my concerns but maybe I should be. I've added I simple manifest file to the jar but get the same error.

Comment: By the way I'm using a recent Firefox download

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the `app` variable in your JS code. See [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html) for an example of running and invoking an applet from JS.

It's probably not a good idea to actually do this and it would be much better to implement what you want to do in pure JS. JS engines have gotten considerably faster in the last few years and browsers have gotten far more strict about the java browser plugin due to the numerous security flaws that have been found/exploited in it.